# Change Solr DisMaxQParser behavior

Tags: solr

My query in Solr is `q={!type=dismax qf='title content' bf=product(f1,f2)^10}data`.

I find that what `DisMaxQParser` does is to compute `max{score_title, score_content} + score_bf`. Now, I want to change its behavior to `max{score_title, score_content} * score_bf`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **ExtendedDismaxQParser** that provides additional functionalities for the dismax query.
The `bf` (boost function) method apply the function result as an addictive value to the score. To apply the function result as a multiplicative value to the score you can use the `boost` method. Your query will be like this:

`q={!type=edismax qf='title content' boost=product(f1,f2)^10}data`